# Historical Simulation VaR in R: VaR calculation produces unreliable result (risk over 100%)

Tags: r, finance, performanceanalytics, risk-analysis

I am am trying to calculate `VaR` using the Historical Simulation method for the `S&P500`. I used the [PerformanceAnalytics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html) package with

```
VaR(P1[1:1000], p =0.95, method = "historical")
```

but I get an error message as below:

> VaR calculation produces unreliable result (risk over 100%) for column: 1 : -1.68435909175

The data that I have used is log returns calculated `as =LN(Today's close/Yesterday's close)*100` and when I calculate the `VaR` using the `percentile` function(`PERCENTILE(B2:B1001,0.05)`), I get the value of `-1.684` as above. I understand that the package was written with returns in mind but I am not sure if I have conceptually made a mistake with my calculation or the error is due to me using log returns.

In this case, would it be better to use normal returns over log returns?

Comment: I don't know the package, but I would assume that if you feed log returns into the function, you get the VaR back as a log return.  Which means that `-1.684` is the 5th percentile log return.  If you want to turn it into a normal return, exponentiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `VaR`uses decimal returns not percentage. See the same message when passing a percentage return to that function. Or use `quantile`.

```
> data(edhec)
> VaR(edhec[,1], p=.95, method="historical")
    Convertible Arbitrage
VaR              -0.01916
> quantile(edhec[,1],c(.05,.95))
      5%      95% 
-0.01916  0.02679 
> VaR(edhec[,1]*100, p=.95, method="historical")
VaR calculation produces unreliable result (risk over 100%) for column: 1 : 1.916
    Convertible Arbitrage
VaR                    -1
> quantile(edhec[,1]*100,c(.05,.95))
    5%    95% 
-1.916  2.679
```